# Display database value in dropdown with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am getting some value from database. Now I want to show that value in dropdown list as selected value. Here is example, I have dropdown list with three option o1, 02, 03. From database I got the value o3, Now I want to show this as selected value.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select id="some_id">
    <option value="o1">Blabla</option>
    <option value="o2">Blabla</option>
    <option value="o3">Blabla</option>
</select>
```

Javascript: `$("#some_id").val("o2");`

The first part `$("#some_id")` just selects the element. You can select multiple elements. (For example, by class instead of id.) I recommend reading "jQuery selectors" here:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dropdown").val(data);
```

Where data is both the `value` attribute (of the `option` element) and the data returned from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#mydropdownlist").val("thevalue");
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this for make selected option in dropdown

```
$("#drop_down_id").val('your value');
```